# How do I create this Java Swing separator UI component?

Tags: user-interface, jtable, toggle, separator

I'm creating a UI in Swing that toggles various JTables that displays different data, much like the example image attached below.

Does anyone know how to create the separator UI component highlighted in the red box, that appears, to toggle its respective UI component?

I've accomplished the intent using JButtons to toggle JPanels, but my UI layout is not as clean compared to the attached example.

TIA!

(Sorry...new users can't post images)

[Example Swing UI](http://db.tt/cTARn0WK)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I used a JButton with a separator graphic painted inside to create the clickable separator graphic.